# Allow Excel user to select operator for formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'd like to setup a spreadsheet that would let the user select the operator to apply to other cells.  For example:  If A1 has 5 and A2 has 10, I'd like the user to be able to select the plus or minus operators from cell A3 (resulting A4 displaying the result of:  A1 + A2 or A1 - A2).

I know I could do this with a IF statement or CHOOSE. But I was wondering if there was something shorter.  I've tried setting A4 to these options but none work as intended.  I want a numerical result, such as 15 or -5

Here's what I've tried:
 - =A1&A3&A2
 - =A1+A3A2

Are there any methods other than IF or CHOOSE?

Answer (score 0):

There's two parts to the answer to this question ...

1. Building a proper string to evaluate, [answered here](https://superuser.com/questions/489089/can-excel-use-formula-input-data-for-cell-references?rq=1)
2. Evaluating that string as if it were a real formula, [answered here](https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula/253437#253437)

---

An example of building the correct string, for the problem you laid out: In Cell A4, put the following formula ...

```
=A1&A3&A2
```

If you put 10 in A1, 11 in A2, and * in A3, this will evaluate to `10*11`

More complex ways of building the string may require use of the `ADDRESS` and/or `INDIRECT` functions.

---

Older versions of Excel carried around a UDF for Evaluate, that does not exist in more recent versions. You would need to create your own UDF such as ...

```
Function myEval(r As Variant) As Variant
    If TypeName(r) = "Range" Then
        myEval = Evaluate(r.Value)
    Else
        myEval = Evaluate(r)
    End If
End Function
```

Following the example, in Cell A5, you could put ...

```
=myEval(A4)
```

which would evaluate to `110`. Or you could replace the contents of Cell A4 with ...

```
=myEval(A1&A3&A2)
```

which wold then evaluate to `110`.